# Safe data retrieved from multiple pages from API

Tags: python, pandas, api, python-requests

I found a solution to print data from several pages from an api:

```
for page in range(1, 3):
    url = "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?page={}".format(page)
    ot_data_response = requests.get(url)
    ot_data = ot_data_response.text
    ot_dataparsed = json.loads(ot_data)
    ot_dataparsedfin = pd.json_normalize(ot_dataparsed, "data")
    print(ot_dataparsedfin)
```

Is there a good way to save all data in one variable/dataframe so i can work with it?

Comment: Have you considered pickle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False, copy=True)
```

For your case, it should be sth like this:

```
json_df_list = []
for page in range(1, 3):
    url = "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?page={}".format(page)
    ot_data_response = requests.get(url)
    ot_data = ot_data_response.text
    ot_dataparsed = json.loads(ot_data)
    ot_dataparsedfin = pd.json_normalize(ot_dataparsed, "data")
    json_df_list.append(ot_dataparsefin)

json_df = pd.concat(json_df_list)
print(json_df)
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!